# How can I calculate the number of the neighbours for each cell?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate the percentage of hexagonal cells in a binary image, which means the number of the cells that have another 6 neighbours cells. For example, the cell labeled with No. 1,2,3,and 4 all have 6 neighbours cells.

I'm looking for a function that can do that in Matlab. I've tried different Matlab functions such as regionprops, and bwconncomp. However, no one works for me. is there any idea.

A simple image is here:

[image]

Comment: Dear Andras, 
In fact, I've tried delete it, but I couldn't I don't why?

Comment: Dear Andras, 
Believe me I did it, but I don't know what's the problem!!. How do you know that someone has posted question or he needs help?. Is there any setting that I can do in my profile? I'm new to this site.

Comment: Alaa I see you've suceeded in deleting your previous question. I've deleted my comments here (since they were obsolete now), I suggest that you do the same with yours (if you hover over your comment with the mouse, a small "x" icon appears near its end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use the [bwlabeln](http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabeln.html) function and a succession of morphological function.

The following code does the job:

```
% load image and post processing
A = imread('LR0gx.png');
I = rgb2gray(A);
I = imcomplement(I);

% labelling of the image
L = bwlabeln(I);

figure; subplot 121;
imagesc(L); title('cells labeling')

% search and count the neighbours using the dilate function
label = unique(L);
for ii = label(2:end)'
    I_temp = L == ii;
    I_temp = bwmorph(I_temp,'dilate',2) - I_temp;
    I_temp2 = L; I_temp2(~I_temp) = 0;
    number_of_neighbours(ii) = size(unique(I_temp2), 1)-1; 
end

L_2 = zeros(size(L));
for ii = label(2:end)'
    L_2(L == ii) = number_of_neighbours(ii);
end
subplot 122;
imagesc(L_2); title('number of neighbours'); colorbar;
```

The result is the following one:

[image]

Ps: you have to remove one to `count` because the partition of the cell is present in the function `unique`.

Pss: the `imcomplement` is needed because `bwlabeln` label white values.

Comment: Dear R. Bergamote
Thank you for your help, but I don't think it solves the problem. What I need is to find the number of neighbours for each cells.

Comment: True! My answer is totally unrelated with the question, let me see about it :D

Comment: @AlaaAlwaisy, I updated the answer, that should be fine now

Comment: @AlaaAlwaisy if an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as accepted. Also, if you feel that an answer is useful, please consider upvoting it. These actions give reputation to those who help you, making their work worth while (also, accepting an answer give you some rep as well).